# cannot get to command line on my ASUS 1015E running Trusty

Tags: command-line

My ASUS 1015E (netbook) has as its OS UBUNTU 14.04.2 LTS (Trusty Tahr). Yesterday, as it ran the weekly updates to the OS and my applications, I lost power, and it died mid-update.

Now I have NO applications listed on the applications panel. I would attempt to rebuild the apt-get package list, but I’m unable to get to a command line.

No matter what I try e.g. holding down <kbd>shift</kbd>, holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (or <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F7</kbd> or <kbd>F8</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd>) I can neither get to a command line nor get UBUNTU to boot to a command line.

Does anyone have a helpful suggestion?

Comment: Try ctrl + alt + F1 to get to a command line shell and log in, re build, try the upgrade again, add any errors to your post

Comment: Can you post an image ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried booting into recovery mode?

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

Or you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get into a virtual console and run commands from there.